Entra SSO returning a 302/502 in a .NET Core site
I have an issue getting SSO to work which is puzzling.
The CallBackPath in the config below matches what is in Azure as the redirect uri, and I can see in the logs that user are being authenticated successfully.  What happens then is they get a 302 in the network tab in dev tools, which becomes a 502 on the page.
I'm unsure if I'm missing anything, or have misconfigured things.  Can anyone advise?
My config:
"Authentication": {
    "ClientId": "xxxxxx",
    "ClientSecret": "yyyyyyyy",
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/zzzzzzz",
    "CallbackPath": "/mypath/mypage",
    "Scope": "openid profile email"
},

the route to the login page where I want to initiate SSO:
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("login")]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties(), OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

and the relevant part from program.cs
.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect("OpenIdConnect", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:ClientSecret"];
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
    options.CallbackPath = builder.Configuration["Authentication:CallbackPath"];
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            // Log successful authentication
            var userId = context.Principal?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value
             ?? context.Principal?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "preferred_username")?.Value
             ?? "Unknown User";
            Log.Information("SSO Log - User {UserId} successfully authenticated via SSO.", userId);

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            Log.Error("SSO Log - Authentication failed: {Error}", context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };

});


May I know the .net core version you are using? Your codes worked well in my side except the public IActionResult Login() method. I created a new MVC app and added the configuration in Program.cs and appsettings.json, I added the [Authorize] attribute before the HomeController. Then when I run my app, it will redirect to Microsoft sign in page and redirct back to the home index page. But if I manually hit /login endpoint, the website will keep redirect to the sign in page and finally told me sign in failed.

One more thing, since you are now working with Microsoft identity, why not using Microsoft.Identity.Web SDK?

return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Content("~/") }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); could you please try this line which set the redirect url. After changing to this line, the infinite loop issue is resolved in my side.

@TinyWang thanks for taking the time to answer>
will your suggestion "return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Content("~/") }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);"  not take me to the root?
What I need to have is
Nothing showing at root - ie a blank page
/login is the initiator for SSO
/accounts/home should be the redirect after authentication

Thank you for your reply, but I'm not very sure about your description. Maybe this test result could help? https://i.sstatic.net/M66N8VWp.png

I'm not sure whether I faced the same issue with your "What happens then is they get a 302 in the network tab in dev tools, which becomes a 502 on the page.", I already described my symptom in the first comment, it's a inifite loop redirection to login page. And my workaround is adding a redirect url in return Challenge. What I set is ~/ so that after signing in it will redirect to the callback path defined in appsetting.json, in my side I set it to /home, then redirect to the url defined in return Challenge  https://i.sstatic.net/AOTG068J.png

@TinyWang thanks for clarifying, what you say makes sense. Unfortunately I don't have an account to test the SSO so I'm waiting on the client trying it.  I'll let you know of successful and you can put the comment as an answer which I will accept.

Thanks a lot for your confirmation : ) and your test result in advance.

I had a test with OP's code in a new .net 8 MVC application which worked well except the Login method in the controller. I added [Authorize] attribute on my controller class so that when I run the application, it would redirect to Microsoft sign in page and it will redirect back to my Home index page after signing succefully. But once I hit login method manually, I will trapped within an infinite redirection loop then gave me an error about sign in.
I deduce the issue might relate to the redirection, therefore I make a change to the Login method return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Content("~/accounts/home") }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); which adding a redirect url.
In my test, it will make the flow to be redirecting to the callback path defined in appsetting.json after signing in successfully, in my side I set it to /home, then redirect to the url defined in return Challenge.


so just to confirm, you say that adding the redirect to the login method worked for you, and it shouldn't matter what path the redirect is as long as it has the authorize attribute?

in my option, yes, no matter the route path is. SSO allows us to not sign in again, so that even if you set the redirect path to portal.azure.com, it should be okay too.
